# how to segment sky & water part in a picture

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to segment the sky and water part in this image.

[Link of the Picture](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10202415977383772&set=a.1061819948755.9871.1323630083&type=1&theater)
I've tried so many methods like k-means, threshold, multi threshold etc. BUt unfortunately nothing worked so well.
 Here is an example of my code(Matlab):

```
img=imread('1.jpg');
im_gray=rgb2gray(img);
b=imadjust(im_gray);
imshow(b);
bw_remove_small=imopen(b,strel('square',5));
imshow(bw_remove_small); %after 1st iteration
m3=medfilt2(bw_remove_small,[18,16]);
imshow(m3);
m3=medfilt2(bw_remove_small,20,20]);
m3=medfilt2(bw_remove_small,[20,20]);
imshow(m3);
I1=m3;
I2=rgb2gray(I1);
I=double(I2);
figure
subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(I1)
subplot(1,3,2)
imshow(I2)
g=kmeans(I(:),4);
J = reshape(g,size(I));
subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(J,[]);
```

Can any one help me?please

Comment: Well, it would be easier to do it manually actually. Tagging your question properly might help though, what language is this ?

Comment: You might consider using the Hough transform (available in MATLAB) on the image's edge map to find the horizon. Then determining which half of the picture contains sky or water isn't too difficult.

Comment: I would try to use the color information. You are currently discarding it with `rgb2gray`.

Answer (score 0):

The picture's two regions are different in hue, texture, and gray level brightness.

The horizon is the best line in the image from our point of view and can be seen by the distinct change in brightness. The brightness will not work with a single threshold because the image brightness is not flat, so use brightness a model of the distribution to flatten out the sky or the water. This implies knowledge of the objective but there are two things that can give you an approximate answer: texture and/or hue.

The hue with a threshold of 120 (derived from the hue histogram) will give you the two regions but will not be divided cleanly and will have overlapping sections. Though using these two sections a model of the brightness can be found.

The same with texture. Using a small fft of the image, subtracting the dc out, then averaging or just summing up the non dc parts will result in a histogram with two peaks that may not be as distinct as the hue's is but is enough to find a threshold and two areas that will allow a model of the brightness to be found.

The key fact is if the sky is modeled properly as a gray surface then you can subtract it out of the image and use a simple threshold to pull it out.

Edge detection is very noisy in this image to be able to easily see the line but if you can pull out the image lines without losing shape then look for a straight and long contour it may take less code/work.

Hope this helps some! I used this to find mountains in the distance when there was not a big difference between the sky and the mountains. Plus I just tried this on your pic and almost got a good answer without a good model of the sky.